# Object values not updating javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
const displayDataTypes = [];
const TypeMap = {
  data: ['type2', 'type3'],
};
  
const Type = {
  title: 'Type',
  values: [
    { label: 'Type-1', value: 'type1', disabled: false },
    { label: 'Type-2', value: 'type2', disabled: false },
    { label: 'type-3', value: 'type3', disabled: false },
    { label: 'type-4', value: 'type4', disabled: false },
    { label: 'type-5', value: 'type5', disabled: false }
  ]
};
  
const TypesSelection = TypeMap['data'];  
  
Type.values.forEach((item) => {
  const tmp = Object.create(item);
  TypesSelection.forEach((type) => {
    if (tmp.value !== type) {
      tmp.disabled = true;
    }
  });
  displayDataTypes.push(tmp);
});
  
console.log(displayDataTypes);
```

In the above code, Every object property disabled is getting true. I need the type2 and type3 should be false and rest should be true because of TypeMap - data.
So the output should be

```
[
  { label: 'Type-1', value: 'type1', disabled: true  },
  { label: 'Type-2', value: 'type2', disabled: false },
  { label: 'type-3', value: 'type3', disabled: false },
  { label: 'type-4', value: 'type4', disabled: true  },
  { label: 'type-5', value: 'type5', disabled: true  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it using the `Array.map` function:

```js
const output = Type.values.map(v => {
  v.disabled = !TypesSelection.includes(v.value);
  return v;
})

console.log(output)
```

This is not only smaller but more readable.

The learn more about the `Array.map` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a nice solution. But wanted to know my mistake in the above code and want the solution with this approach also.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the iteration. At some point **tmp.value** will be **'type2'** and **type** will be **'type3'**. This will cause disabled to get set to true for the 'type2' object.

I think this does what you want.

```js
const Type = {
  title: 'Type',
  values: [
{
  label: 'Type-1',
  value: 'type1',
  disabled: false,
},
{
  label: 'Type-2',
  value: 'type2',
  disabled: false,
},
{
  label: 'type-3',
  value: 'type3',
  disabled: false,
},
{
  label: 'type-4',
  value: 'type4',
  disabled: false,
},
{
  label: 'type-5',
  value: 'type5',
  disabled: false,
},
  ],
};
  
const TypeMap = {
  data: ['type2', 'type3']
};
  
const TypesSelection = TypeMap['data'];
const displayDataTypes = Type.values.map(item => {
  const shallowCopy = {...item};
  if (TypesSelection.every(type => (type !== shallowCopy.value))) {
shallowCopy.disabled = true;
  }
  return shallowCopy;
});
  
console.log(displayDataTypes);
```

I would recommend not using a property named "disable" because it causes confusing double negative situations. Instead use "enabled". This is of course assuming you have control of the property names.

If you don't need to preserve the initial "disabled" states on the copies and if you don't need copies then use the much smaller / simpler implementation in Ilijaz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because the correct result is being overwritten by other iterations of your inner loop.

Your current structure is 2-step:

1. Loop over each value in `Type.values`
2. Loop over each value in `TypeMap.data` and check if the two elements *don't* match

As a result of that second step, even elements that match will get compared to another element that *doesn't* match, causing the conditional code to get executed anyway.

Eg.:

1. Outer loop:

   1. item is `type2`
2. Inner loop:

   1. type is `type2`
   2. check the condition: `type2 !== type2` is `false`
   3. Skip conditional code
3. Inner loop

   1. type is now `type3`
   2. check the condition: `type3 !== type3` is **`true`**
   3. run conditional code, set `disabled` to `true`

As such, all `disabled`s will *always* be set to true.

---

Using a nested `forEach` isn't very well suited for this use case, since there's no straightforward way to avoid this problem. If you still want to use `forEach` for the outer loop, you can, or you could simplify further with `map()`, as [@Ilijaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12619406/ilijaz) suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63910609/11047824).

Using `forEach` and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const displayDataTypes = [];

const TypeMap = {
  data: ['type2', 'type3'],
};

const Type = {
  title: 'Type',
  values: [{
      label: 'Type-1',
      value: 'type1',
      disabled: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Type-2',
      value: 'type2',
      disabled: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'type-3',
      value: 'type3',
      disabled: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'type-4',
      value: 'type4',
      disabled: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'type-5',
      value: 'type5',
      disabled: false,
    },
  ],
};

const TypesSelection = TypeMap['data'];

Type.values.forEach((item) => {
  const tmp = Object.create(item);
  if (!TypesSelection.includes(tmp.value)) {
    tmp.disabled = true;
  }
  displayDataTypes.push(tmp);
});

console.log(displayDataTypes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```